# Guideline for Real time acquisition of log file with telnet MATLAB

Tags: linux, matlab, real-time, telnet

I have a system that I would like to process some data with MATLAB and sending back some commands based on the results from MATLAB  process (very short process).

1. I thought of creating a log file and sending it to the MATLAB pc with tftp, which MATLAB should listen to "changes" in the folder and process the log file then feedback through telnet command.
2. Directly ask MATLAB to grab/capture the log from the connected system do the process and feedback the command based on the results.

also if it possible , I want to be able to switch between two process methods in real time. Meaning can I get MATLAB to listen to a command from the MATLAB PC, and switch between the two methods ?

the mentioned system works under Linux environment.

any guidelines or references would be great.

Comment: Is the a specific reason you are using files to transfer data? That typically can cause problems with Matlab reading the file faster than it is written, causing incomplete data to be read.

Comment: No no , in section 2 i meant by capturing , that i'll ask Matlab to pass the command that displays the log , lets say for one sec of capturing . But how can i grab the text for  processing it. I already have the code that read the log file and analyze the text takes the data and process it.

Comment: So I write my script following section 1 , with some success. I'm getting the log file that I want process and I want to send some commands based on the results, e.g controlling on FPGA define some parameters etc... . but the situation is that I want to be able to follow those changes. So I grabbed another PC logged to the system and continuously reading/displaying the values I want, but I don't see any changes although my script working well and I can see that I creating new log files in the system over and over. Is it something with the tcpip of matlab ?